# SQL Implied Null values in joined table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, null

In joining two tables with a one to many relationship, I want a result displaying all the values in the many table with `null` values in the one table.

Here's an example:

**tbl_Platform: PriKey = PlatformID**

```
PlatformID  PlatformDesc
1   Application
2   Cloud
3   Storage
4   Backup
```

**tbl_Missed: PriKey= CustomerID+Week+PlatformID**

```
CustomerID  Week    Missed     Platform ID
49          1       2017-05-19  1
```

Output desired:

```
CustomerID  Week    Missed  PlatformDesc
49  1   2017-05-19  Application
49  1   null    Cloud
49  1   null    Storage
49  1   null    Backup
```

The closest I've been able to come is using a cross join as follows:

```
SELECT        
   dbo.tbl_Missed.CustomerID, 
   dbo.tbl_Missed.Week, 
   dbo.tbl_Missed.Missed, 
   dbo.tbl_Platform.PlatformDesc
FROM
   dbo.tbl_Platform 
CROSS JOIN dbo.tbl_MissedSPT
```

Which gives me:

```
49  1   2017-05-19  Application
49  1   2017-05-19  Cloud
49  1   2017-05-19  Storage
49  1   2017-05-19  Backup
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems as if you want to take the value of attribute `missed` if there is a match in `platformID`, and `null` otherwise. Try the following (hope there are no typos):

```
SELECT        
   dbo.tbl_Missed.CustomerID, 
   dbo.tbl_Missed.week, 
   CASE WHEN dbo.tbl_Missed.PlatformID = dbo.tbl_Platform.PlatformID
               THEN dbo.tbl_Missed.missed 
               ELSE NULL
   END as missed, 
   dbo.tbl_Platform.PlatformDesc
FROM dbo.tbl_Platform CROSS JOIN dbo.tbl_MissedSPT
```